# Viber Bot REST API - Getting Messages from Bot

Tags: php, api, viber

Good day! This question is related to the documentation in this link https://developers.viber.com/docs/api/rest-bot-api/

I am trying to create a viber bot but I don't seem to know what am I missing. I am not entirely sure if I fully understand the documents either but this is what I have done so far

1 . Create a viber public account

2 . Create SSL server for callbacks (https://eelhisales.com/_demo/viber_bot/index.php)

3 . Setup Webhook using PostMan with parameter as url server and viber bot token

**Problem:** 
I am able to send messages to the bot using POST request but if I can't get the messages sent through the application.

My Goal is to get the messages sent through the bot on viber app itself and sent back the responses from the server.

Images here :

[postman webhook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UM6PV.png)

[Post Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9Y1e.png)

[Bot history](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15zLw.png)

index.php

```
        <?php

        // loading access token
        require_once 'config.php'; // $access_token = "YourAccessTokenHere";

        $request = file_get_contents("php://input");
        $input = json_decode($request, true);

        if($input['event'] == 'webhook') {
            $webhook_response['status'] = 0;
            $webhook_response['status_message'] = "ok";
            $webhook_response['event_types'] = "delivered";
            echo json_encode($webhook_response);
            die;
        }

        elseif($input['event'] == 'message') {
            $text_received = $input['message']['text'];
            $sender_id = $input['sender']['id'];
            $sender_name = $input['sender']['name'];

            // $log_msg = "\n";
            // $log_msg .= "SenderName => ".$sender_name;
            // $log_msg .= "SenderID => ".$sender_id;
            // error_log($log_msg, 3, "log.log");

            $data['auth_token'] = $access_token;
            $data['receiver'] = $sender_id;

            if($text_received == 'text') {
                // =================================
                // Text message
                // =================================
                $data['type'] = "text";
                $data['text'] = "Hello world!";
            }
            else if($text_received == 'picture') {
                // =================================
                // Picture message
                // =================================
                $data['type'] = "picture";
                $data['text'] = "Google Logo"; // Photo Description
                $data['media'] = "https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png";
            }
            else if($text_received == 'video') {
                // =================================
                // Video message
                // =================================
                $data['type'] = "video";
                $data['media'] = "https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/04/file_example_MP4_480_1_5MG.mp4";
                $data['size'] = 1024000; // size of video in bytes
            }
            else if($text_received == 'file') {
                // =================================
                // File message
                // =================================
                $data['type'] = "file";
                $data['media'] = "https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/10/file-sample_150kB.pdf";
                $data['size'] = 102400; // size of video in bytes
                $data['file_name'] = 'FileNameHere.pdf'; // file name + extension
            }
            else if($text_received == 'contact') {
                // =================================
                // Contact message
                // =================================
                $data['type'] = "contact";
                $data['contact'] = [
                    'name' => 'Ko Ko',
                    'phone_number' => '+972511123123'
                ];
            }
            else if($text_received == 'location') {
                // =================================
                // Location message
                // =================================
                $data['type'] = "location";
                $data['location'] = [
                    'lat' => '16.812775',
                    'lon' => '96.129981'
                ];
            }
            else if($text_received == 'url') {
                // =================================
                // URL message
                // =================================
                $data['type'] = "url";
                $data['media'] = 'https://www.google.com';
            }
            else if($text_received == 'sticker') {
                // =================================
                // Sticker message
                // =================================
                $data['type'] = "sticker";
                $data['sticker_id'] = 40133;
            }
            else if($text_received == 'rich_media') {
                // =================================
                // Rich Media message / Carousel content message
                // =================================
                $data['type'] = "rich_media";
                $data['min_api_version'] = 7;
                $data['rich_media'] = 
                [
                    "Type" => "rich_media",
                    "ButtonsGroupColumns" => 6,
                    "ButtonsGroupRows" => 7,
                    "BgColor" => "#FFFFFF",
                    "Buttons" => [
                        [
                            "Columns" => 3,
                            "Rows" => 3,
                            "ActionType" => "open-url",
                            "ActionBody" => "https://www.google.com",
                            "Image" => "https://png.pngtree.com/png-clipart/20190612/original/pngtree-green-url-png-image_3478473.jpg"
                        ],
                        [
                            "Columns" => 3,
                            "Rows" => 3,
                            "ActionType" => "open-url",
                            "ActionBody" => "https://www.google.com",
                            "Image" => "https://png.pngtree.com/png-clipart/20190612/original/pngtree-green-url-png-image_3478473.jpg"
                        ],
                        [
                            "Columns" => 6,
                            "Rows" => 2,
                            "Text" => "<font color=#323232><b>Headphones with Microphone, On-ear Wired [earphones</b></font><font color=#777777><br>Sound Intone </font><font [color=#6fc133>$17.99</font>",
                            "ActionType" => "open-url",
                            "ActionBody" => "https://www.google.com",
                            "TextSize" => "medium",
                            "TextVAlign" => "middle",
                            "TextHAlign" => "left"
                        ],
                        [
                            "Columns" => 6,
                            "Rows" => 1,
                            "ActionType" => "reply",
                            "ActionBody" => "https://www.google.com",
                            "Text" => "<font color=#ffffff>Buy</font>",
                            "TextSize" => "large",
                            "TextVAlign" => "middle",
                            "TextHAlign" => "middle",
                            "Image" => "https://png.pngtree.com/png-clipart/20190612/original/pngtree-green-url-png-image_3478473.jpg"
                        ],
                        [
                            "Columns" => 6,
                            "Rows" => 1,
                            "ActionType" => "reply",
                            "ActionBody" => "https://www.google.com",
                            "Text" => "<font color=#8367db>MORE DETAILS</font>",
                            "TextSize" => "small",
                            "TextVAlign" => "middle",
                            "TextHAlign" => "middle"
                        ],
                        [
                            "Columns" => 6,
                            "Rows" => 3,
                            "ActionType" => "open-url",
                            "ActionBody" => "https://www.google.com",
                            "Image" => "https://png.pngtree.com/png-clipart/20190612/original/pngtree-green-url-png-image_3478473.jpg"
                        ],
                        [
                            "Columns" => 6,
                            "Rows" => 2,
                            "Text" => "<font color=#323232><b>Hanes Men's Humor Graphic T-Shirt</b></font><font color=#777777><br>Hanes</font><font color=#6fc133>$10.99</font>",
                            "ActionType" => "open-url",
                            "ActionBody" => "https://www.google.com",
                            "TextSize" => "medium",
                            "TextVAlign" => "middle",
                            "TextHAlign" => "left"
                        ],
                        [
                            "Columns" => 6,
                            "Rows" => 1,
                            "ActionType" => "reply",
                            "ActionBody" => "https://www.google.com",
                            "Text" => "<font color=#ffffff>Buy</font>",
                            "TextSize" => "large",
                            "TextVAlign" => "middle",
                            "TextHAlign" => "middle",
                            "Image" => "https://png.pngtree.com/png-clipart/20190612/original/pngtree-green-url-png-image_3478473.jpg"
                        ],
                        [
                            "Columns" => 6,
                            "Rows" => 1,
                            "ActionType" => "reply",
                            "ActionBody" => "https://www.google.com",
                            "Text" => "<font color=#8367db>MORE DETAILS</font>",
                            "TextSize" => "small",
                            "TextVAlign" => "middle",
                            "TextHAlign" => "middle"
                        ]
                    ]
                ];
            }
            else if($text_received == 'keyboard') {
                // =================================
                // Keyboard
                // =================================
                $data['min_api_version'] = 7;
                $data['type'] = "text";
                $data['text'] = "Hello world to Keyboard";
                $data['keyboard'] = [
                    'Type' => "keyboard",
                    'DefaultHeight' => true,
                    'Buttons' => [
                        [
                            'ActionType' => 'reply',
                            'ActionBody' => 'reply to me',
                            'Text' => 'Key text',
                            'TextSize' => "regular"
                        ]
                    ]
                ];
            }
            else {
                $data['type'] = "text";
                $data['text'] = "Hi!".$sender_name." ($sender_id)";
            }

            if($text_received != 'broadcast') {
                sendMessage($data);
            } else {
                $data['min_api_version'] = 2;
                $data['type'] = 'text';
                $data['broadcast_list'] = [
                    'QfzEzLbtpNeRjjFEe55VKw=='
                ];
                $data['text'] = 'broadcasting message to all subscribers';
                broadcastMessage($data);
            }
        }

        function sendMessage($data) {
            try {
                $url = "https://chatapi.viber.com/pa/send_message";
                $jsonData = json_encode($data);
                // print_r($jsonData);
                $ch = curl_init($url);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonData);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
                $result = curl_exec($ch);
                return $result;
            } catch(\Exception $ex) {
                error_log("\nYou messed up!", 3, "log.log");
            }
        }

        function broadcastMessage($data) {
            try {
                $url = "https://chatapi.viber.com/pa/broadcast_message";
                $jsonData = json_encode($data);
                // print_r($jsonData);
                $ch = curl_init($url);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonData);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
                $result = curl_exec($ch);
                return $result;
            } catch(\Exception $ex) {
                error_log("\nYou messed up!", 3, "log.log");
            }
        }
```